# Kotlin JS and GWT interop

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, kotlin

Kotlin JS compiler emits Java Script code from Kotlin code.
GWT emits Java Script code from Java source code.

Is it possible in easy way to connect JS generated by Kotlin Compiler and JS generated by GWT compiler? How?

Comment: Have you tried to make them interop, if so, what did you discover?

Comment: I didn't try yet. But I found TeaVM, which possibly can solve my problem in a very elegant way without using GWT at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's simplest way to interop now is interop through javascript as far as both have functionality for that.